# RDKit not working on Heroku

Tags: deployment, update, heroku, package-install

I want to deploy a Flask app on Heroku that uses the RDKit package. I installed it with the requirements.txt and it worked fine, but since the new version rdkit-pypi==2021.9.2 it doesn't work anymore. The import statement alone leads to an application error.

The Flask app is working perfectly on the localhost and I'm 100% sure that the problem is the RDKit installation on Heroku. Please help!